# generate varying objects of class by different mutuable attribute

Tags: python-2.7

I would like to generate multiple objects of a class where the differ only by a the attribute of the class. Let me make an example

```
class A:
    ...:     def __init__(self, x):
    ...:         self.x = x
    ...:     def update_dic(self, dictionary):
    ...:         self.x.update(dictionary)
    ...: 

In [55]: list_class = list()

In [56]: shared_dict = {'a': 1}
```

Now I would like to generate 10 different objects where they share the `shared_dict` but update it differently:

```
In [58]: for i in range(0, 10):
    ...:     obj = A(shared_dict)
    ...:     obj.update_dic({'b': i})
    ...:     list_class.append(obj)
    ...:
```

as we can see in the following output they are different objects:

```
In [59]: list_class
Out[59]: 
[<__main__.A instance at 0xac0c7d6c>,
 <__main__.A instance at 0xac13914c>,
 <__main__.A instance at 0xac0c7d8c>,
 <__main__.A instance at 0xac0c7dac>,
 <__main__.A instance at 0xac0c7dcc>,
 <__main__.A instance at 0xac0c7e0c>,
 <__main__.A instance at 0xac0c7e2c>,
 <__main__.A instance at 0xac0c7e4c>,
 <__main__.A instance at 0xac0c7e6c>,
 <__main__.A instance at 0xac0c7e8c>]
```

However, they get all the same element `b`:

```
In [60]: [_.x for _ in list_class]
Out[60]: 
[{'a': 1, 'b': 9},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 9},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 9},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 9},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 9},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 9},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 9},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 9},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 9},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 9}]
```

I guess this has something to do with a list being a mutable object. But what exactly is going on and more important how can I resolve it, i.e. getting an output like this:

```
In [60]: [_.x for _ in list_class]
Out[60]: 
[{'a': 1, 'b': 0},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 1},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 2},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 3},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 4},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 5},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 6},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 7},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 8},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 9}]
```

Comment: No, the issue is that they share the same dict.

Comment: You have a shared dict that you don't want to share?

Comment: Well I want the first part of the dict to be the same. In the real case the first part of the dict is much more complicated so I don't want to repeat it there. Can I just use a `A(shared_dict.copy())` when I create the different object?

Comment: Use two dicts, and add them when the value is asked for.